# socket_timeout overriding BRPOP timeout param in StrictRedis

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I'm running into an issue where a re-used StrictRedis connection with a socket_timeout parameter is overriding a brpop command with an unlimited timeout. Any ideas?

```
redis_audience = StrictRedis(host=host,
                             port=port,
                             db=1,
                             socket_timeout=10,  # the culprit
                             socket_connect_timeout=10)

redis_audience.brpop(key, timeout=0)  # this will fail after 10 seconds
```

Comment: Don't set socket timeouts if you don't want the socket to time out.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz — This is just a code snippet. I need the socket_timeout for error handling another command that might hang.

Comment: That's the part you need to fix, not this part which is doing exactly what you asked it to do.